# You do not have permission to create Navigation Menus - Twenty Twenty-Two theme

Tags: menus, navigation, theme-twenty-twenty-two

I have a WP Multisite, where I am the super-admin of the Network and the only admin (also super-admin) of this particular site.

Everything is working fine, but whenever I try to edit/add Navigation menu, it keeps giving this error **you do not have permission to create Navigation Menus**

I have checked database, the wp_capabilities in wp_usermeta are `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}` which I checked should be for the admins. The value is also 10 in wp_user_level column.

What else can I do/check in order to change the Navigation Menu?
Thanks in advance.